# Probability after several experiments

Tags: probability

If a general wins a battle, there is 80% chance that he is a good general.

If a general loses a battle, there is a 10% chance that he is a good general.

i.e. Let G be general is a good general, W be general winning a battle

P(G|W)=0.8
p(G|!W)=0.1

So after 5 battles, the general loses 1 and wins 4 battles, and the battles are independent
what is the probability of him being a good general?

I'm confused because the probability is after 5 experiments, and I cannot simply multiple them since it would make sense for the probability to increase after successful battles.

I'm thinking of taking the average, as in $\frac{0.8*4+0.1}{5}$

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expected to use the binomial theorem.  If he wins one and loses four, you have ${5 \choose 1}0.8^10.1^4$ chance he is a good general and ${5 \choose 1}0.2^10.9^4$ chance he is not.  Normalize to make the sum $1$ and you are there.